# Calling internal functions via dll injection - runtime error

Tags: c++, dll-injection, call

I am trying to modify closed source game client that works with my game server. The purpose of that is being able to add new graphical elements into the client.

I have read a lot of tutorials about dll injection and in the end theres the code I made:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

#define BASE_ADDR 0x00400000

DWORD WINAPI MyThread(LPVOID);
DWORD g_threadID;
HMODULE g_hModule;
void __stdcall CallFunction(int&, int&, int&, int&, int&, int&, int&, int&);
void __stdcall typeText(int&, const char*);


//must be at least one function to prevent crash
__declspec(dllexport) int APIENTRY Func(LPVOID lpParam)
{//empty function
    return 0;
}


//main func
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{

    DWORD myThreadID;
    HANDLE myHandle;


    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        g_hModule = hModule;
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hModule);
        CreateThread(NULL, NULL, &MyThread, NULL, NULL, &g_threadID);
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}


DWORD WINAPI MyThread(LPVOID)
{
    int i1 = 1;
    int i2 = 10;
    int i3 = 10;
    int i4 = 200;
    int i5 = 200;
    int i6 = 60;
    int i7 = 0;
    int i8 = 0;


    while (true)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F3) & 1) //Set F3 as hotkey
        {
            // call GUI window (do it before login)
            CallFunction(i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8);


            //display text from char (do it after login)
            //typeText(i1, "halo halo");
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F4) & 1)
            break;
        Sleep(100);
    }
    FreeLibraryAndExitThread(g_hModule, 0);


    /* another way to call function?
    typedef void tipo(int& p1, int& p2, int& p3, int& p4, int& p5, int& p6, int& p7, int& p8);
    void(*func)(int& p1, int& p2, int& p3, int& p4, int& p5, int& p6, int& p7, int& p8);
    func = (tipo*)0x490C60;
    func(i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8);
    */

    return 0;
}

//0x004067C0, pattern = (int, char*)
void __stdcall typeText(int& type, const char* text)
{
    typedef void(__stdcall *pFunctionAddress)(int&, const char*);
    pFunctionAddress pMySecretFunction = (pFunctionAddress)(0x004067C0);
    pMySecretFunction(type, text);
}

//const DWORD DrawSkinExAddress =0x490C60;.
//typedef void TF_DRAWSKIN(int nSurface, int X, int Y, int W, int H, int SkinId, int dX, int dY);
void __stdcall CallFunction(int& p1, int& p2, int& p3, int& p4, int& p5, int& p6, int& p7, int& p8)
{
    typedef void(__stdcall *pFunctionAddress)(int&, int&, int&, int&, int&, int&, int&, int&);
    pFunctionAddress pMySecretFunction = (pFunctionAddress)(0x490C60);
    pMySecretFunction(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8);
}
```

I can successfully inject it and run the client. When I try to call definied there function (Press F3 to do it), the client crashes. the runtime error shows up (picture presenting error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sL1m.jpg ) and client crashes. I think theres problem with the method I call the functions. The addresses and variables are fine I think because if I try to do it on another random addresses the client just crash normally (app not responding).

I have tried replacing stdcall with cdecl but nothing has changed.

Comment: Where do you get the address of function you want to call? It shouldn't be hard-code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The address I used was wrong :|